# Crystal Reports 2008 / Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've created a number of Crystal 2008 reports that are running in InfoView. This isn't working out too well, and I'd like to create my own Crystal Reports report viewer application in VS 2010. I'm too familiar with hosting Crystal reports inside a C# application.

So I guess a couple basic questions. 1) Does VS 2010 contain a Crystal Reports viewer that will allow me to display my Crystal 2008 reports. 2) Is there anything else I need to display Crystal 2008 reports in a C# application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Crystal for Visual Studio 2010 which will provide you with the CrystalReportViewer Control. As far as I am aware there are no issues with loading 2008 reports into VS 2010.

Comment: give me link too for crystal report 2008